# AG-GRID export all Data As Excel with custom pagination

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are using our custom pagination rendering only 20 records in the ag-grid enterprise version at a time. I want to export excel with all pages Data at once.

I'm having following code:-

```
this._gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({ fileName: 'projects_list', sheetName: 'Projects', headerRowHeight: 35});


AgGridPagination = require('/components/ag_grid_pagination')
agGridPagination = AgGridPagination.initialize(@_gridOptions)
@_gridOptions.onPaginationChanged = agGridPagination.renderPagination.bind(agGridPagination)
AgGridPagination.initializePaginationListeners()
```

**exportDataAsExcel** exports only selected Page, while I want to export all the data from all the pages.

is there any way to get all the data using **exportDataAsExcel** ? I'm using AG-Grid in a Ruby on Rails application.